# Drop Julia array dimensions of length 1

Tags: arrays, julia

Say if I have a 5D Array with size 1024x1024x1x1x100. How can I make a new array that is 1024x1024x100?

The following works if you know which dimensions you want to keep ahead of time:

```
arr = arr[:, :, 1, 1, :]
```

But **I don't know which dimensions are what size ahead of time** and I would like to only keep dimensions given a boolean mask; something like this...

```
arr2 = arr[(size(arr) .> 1)]
```

Comment: Try `squeeze(a,(find(size(a).==1)...))` and in general `squeeze`, `reshape`, and `size` should do manipulations.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @DanGetz `squeeze` works really well for this, could you write it as an answer and I'll mark it and solved? Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard This is for some rearchitecting that I'm doing for https://github.com/tlnagy/OMETIFF.jl I'm reading in 5D images from the dataset and they may or not actually need all 5 dimensions. It makes the code simpler to drop the dimensions after reading in the image instead of earlier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `squeeze` function was defined specifically for the purpose of removing dimensions of length 1. From the manual:

> Base.squeeze — Function.
>
> `squeeze(A, dims)`
>
> Remove the dimensions
> specified by dims from array A. Elements of dims must be unique and
> within the range `1:ndims(A)`. `size(A,i)` must equal 1 for all `i` in `dims`.

To "squeeze" all the dimensions of size 1 (when they are unknown in advance), we need to find them and make them into a tuple. This is accomplished by `((size(arr).==1)...)`. So the result is:

```
squeeze(a,(find(size(a).==1)...))
```

Thanks to a comment by Olivier, here is an:

UPDATE: `dropdims` is now (Julia 1.9 as of writing) the preferred way to squeeze out size 1 dimensions. For example, to drop all the size 1 dimensions from M:

```
dropdims(M,dims=tuple(findall(size(M).==1)...))
```

If the dimensions are known, then it might be better to specify them explicitly instead of using the above `findall` method.

Comment: I actually may end up using `reshape` for my case since `squeeze` allocates a new array, but `squeeze` seems purpose built for this case.

Comment: @tlnagy `squeeze` is implemented using `reshape`, so you can use it, and it doesn't allocate a new array (just test it by modifying an element)

Comment: It seems that `Base.squeeze` [has been deprecated](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/release-0.7/NEWS.md#deprecated-or-removed) in favor of `dropdims` in Julia 0.7.0.

Comment: @OlivierVerdier Added `dropdims` to answer. Thanks for the tip.