# dropping singleton dimensions in julia

Tags: julia

Just playing around with Julia (1.0) and one thing that I need to use a lot in Python/numpy/matlab is the `squeeze` function to drop the singleton dimensions.

I found out that one way to do this in Julia is:

```
a = rand(3, 3, 1);
a = dropdims(a, dims = tuple(findall(size(a) .== 1)...))
```

The second line seems a bit cumbersome and not easy to read and parse instantly (this could also be my bias that I bring from other languages). However, I wonder if this is the canonical way to do this in Julia?

Comment: I can't think of anything significantly simpler than what you've done. I guess there is an argument here that calls to `dropdims(a)` should fall back on the method you've defined above, i.e. automatically drop all singleton dimensions. EDIT: turns out it has been extensively discussed, see [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/11838), and [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/22000)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Drop Julia array dimensions of length 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46289554/drop-julia-array-dimensions-of-length-1), except answers here are more complete and use the more recent `dropdims` instead of the deprecated `squeeze`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The actual answer to this question surprised me. What you are asking could be rephrased as:

> why doesn't `dropdims(a)` remove all singleton dimensions?

I'm going to quote Tim Holy from the [relevant issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/22000) here:

> it's not possible to have squeeze(A) return a type that the compiler
>   can infer---the sizes of the input matrix are a runtime variable, so
>   there's no way for the compiler to know how many dimensions the output
>   will have. So it can't possibly give you the type stability you seek.

Type stability aside, there are also some other surprising implications of what you have written. For example, note that:

```
julia> f(a) = dropdims(a, dims = tuple(findall(size(a) .== 1)...))
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(rand(1,1,1))
0-dimensional Array{Float64,0}:
0.9939103383167442
```

In summary, including such a method in `Base` Julia would encourage users to use it, resulting in potentially type-unstable code that, under some circumstances, will not be fast (something the core developers are strenuously trying to avoid). In languages like Python, rigorous type-stability is not enforced, and so you will find such functions.

Of course, nothing stops you from defining your own method as you have. And I don't think you'll find a significantly simpler way of writing it. For example, the proposition for `Base` that was not implemented was the method:

```
function squeeze(A::AbstractArray)
    singleton_dims = tuple((d for d in 1:ndims(A) if size(A, d) == 1)...)
    return squeeze(A, singleton_dims)
end
```

Just be aware of the potential implications of using it.

Comment: Thanks for this fantastic research as well. I guess there is no way to do this in an type efficient manner due to the runtime dependence on size?

Comment: @Luca Yes, that's exactly the issue. Note that in many use-cases, the type-stability performance hit would be minor, and can be mitigated using techniques like barrier functions, so don't be entirely discouraged from doing it. You just need to be aware of the implications. (and I'm sure you can see now why they chose not to include it in `Base`)

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I can see why it is not part of the standard library and it is great to see the discussion that goes into these decisions!

Comment: @ColinTBowers did you mean to say `return dropdims(A, singleton_dims)` in that last snippet?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou No, I actually copied that snippet directly from the PR that I linked in my answer. The PR is from mid-2017, back when it was `squeeze` not `dropdims`. I guess I could have changed it to `dropdims`, but all I was really trying to demonstrate is that the submitted PR wasn't significantly different to the method that the OP came up with. Also I was lazily copy/pasting :-)

Comment: @ColinTBowers ah yes makes sense now :)

Answer (score 10):

Let me simply add that "uncontrolled" `dropdims` (drop any singleton dimension) is a frequent source of bugs. For example, suppose you have some loop that asks for a data array `A` from some external source, and you run `R = sum(A, dims=2)` on it and then get rid of all singleton dimensions. But then suppose that one time out of 10000, your external source returns `A` for which `size(A, 1)` happens to be 1: boom, suddenly you're dropping more dimensions than you intended and perhaps at risk for grossly misinterpreting your data.

If you specify those dimensions manually instead (e.g., `dropdims(R, dims=2)`) then you are immune from bugs like these.

Comment: This is a valid point and I also guess one of the concerns behind the design of the Base function in Julia.

Answer (score 6):

You can get rid of `tuple` in favor of a comma `,`:

```
dropdims(a, dims = (findall(size(a) .== 1)...,))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit surprised at Colin's revelation; surely something relying on 'reshape' is type stable? (plus, as a bonus, returns a view rather than a copy).

```
julia> function squeeze( A :: AbstractArray )
         keepdims = Tuple(i for i in size(A) if i != 1);
         return reshape( A, keepdims );
       end;

julia> a = randn(2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,6,1,7);

julia> size( squeeze(a) )
(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

No?

Comment: hmmmm ok. So since reshape returns a view, it basically can cast it to whatever inferred datatype would be and there is no penalty? I am afraid I am too new to Julia to comment or judge this. I am hoping someone with more experience would weigh in.

Comment: No, this isn't inferrable, because an array's size isn't encoded by the type system; consider `typeof(squeeze(rand(3,5)))` vs `typeof(squeeze(rand(1,5)))` vs `typeof(squeeze(rand(1,1)))`. It's the `keepdims` part that's not inferrable, not the `reshape`.

Comment: thanks for clarifying @tholy . Is that really that important from an efficiency point of view though? It seems to me that such a squeeze function would be a simple wrapper calling optimised methods under the hood. Since there are no further instructions there, I don't see what a compiled version would offer more. Am I missing the bigger picture here?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I noticed something else which is interesting in your answer (and a bit unrelated). Tuple returns a tuple as expected but tuple (without the capitalisation) returns a generator. Is that also something idiomatic in Julia? I tried looking in the docs but could not find anything.

Comment: @Luca it's not that it's idiomatic, it's more that they represent different things. `Tuple` is the type and its corresponding constructor which expects an iterable argument for initialisation. `tuple` is an independent function which takes a _sequence_ of arguments and constructs a corresponding tuple, presumably by calling `Tuple` appropriately under the hood. This _used_ to be a common pattern (e.g. Julia 0.3 had `int64` as the function converting to `Int64`, but that's gone now in favour of using the constructor directly), but not so much these days. Things keep changing tho, so, who knows.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou, it depends: if you pass the resulting array to a function `f`, you may be fine---julia will have to do "dynamic dispatch" once, to look up which version of `f` to use (possibly compiling it if necessary). On the other hand, if you e.g. iterate over the values in the array within the same function, it could be bad because Julia has to do dynamic dispatch for each entry. See https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#kernal-functions-1 for similar considerations. But see also https://julialang.org/blog/2018/08/union-splitting.